# My server crashes when I close my client

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, tcp

Using visual studios Windows forms on c#, I'm making a chatprogram with unlimited clients and one server. The server has to be activated before I connect any client. However, after connecting one or more clients and closing one of them, the server crashes. I can nor close it or send any data from my clients to it without getting an error. The CPU usage of my computer rises to 50% during the crash. After I manage to close the server through task manager, different code lines are highlighted, indicating the error.

Here's my server code:

```
namespace TCPa
{   // skapar en lista med tcp clients 
     // säg till så att send funktioner tar tcp clients som input i 
     metoderna och referera till metoderna
    // och loopa genom listan, som kallar metoden i lista.


public partial class Server : Form
{
    TcpClient klient = null;
    List<TcpClient> klientLista = new List<TcpClient>();
    TcpListener lyssnare;
    int port = 0;

    public Server()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void btnTaEmot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            port = int.Parse(tbxPort.Text);
            if (port >= 1024 && port <= 65535)
            {
                les(port);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Skriv in ett giltigt portnummer mellan 1024 och 65535");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Skriv in ett giltigt portnummer mellan 1024 och 65535");
        }

    }
    public void les(int portT)
    {
        btnTaEmot.Enabled = false;
        tbxPort.Enabled = false;

        try
        {
            lyssnare = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, portT);
            lyssnare.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.Message, Text);
            return;
        }
        StartAccepting();
    }
    public async void StartAccepting()
    {
         try
        {
            klient = await lyssnare.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            klientLista.Add(klient);
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.Message, Text);
            return;
        }
        StartReading(klient);
        StartAccepting();
    }
    public async void StartReading(TcpClient k)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int n = 0;
        try
        {
///NEW
            n = await k.GetStream().ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 1024); 
            if (n <= 0)
            {
                klient.Close();
            }
////NEW
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.Message, Text);
            return;
        }
        StartSending(k, Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, n));
        tbxLogg.AppendText(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, n));
        StartReading(k);
    }
    public async void StartSending(TcpClient klientSomSkickar, string message)
    {
        if (klientLista.Count > 0)
        {
            byte[] utData = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(message);            
            foreach (TcpClient klient in klientLista)
            {
                try
                {   
                    if (klient != klientSomSkickar)
                    {
                        await klient.GetStream().WriteAsync(utData, 0, utData.Length);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(error.Message, Text); return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private void Server_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        lyssnare.Stop();
        if (klient != null && klient.Connected)
        {
            klient.Close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here's my client code

```
namespace Klient
{
public partial class Klient : Form
{
    TcpClient klient = new TcpClient();
    public Klient()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        btnSend.Enabled = false;
    }
    private void btnAnslut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Connect();
    }

    private async void Connect()
    {
        IPAddress adress = IPAddress.Parse(tbxIP.Text);
        int port = int.Parse(tbxPort.Text);

        try
        {
            await klient.ConnectAsync(adress, port);
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.Message, Text);
            return;
        }
        if (klient.Connected)
        {
            btnAnslut.Enabled = false;
            btnSend.Enabled = true;
            tbxNmn.Enabled = false;
            tbxMedd.Focus();
        }
        StartReading(klient);
    }

    private async void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (klient.Connected)
        {
            string namn = tbxNmn.Text;
            string tid = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm tt");

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbxMedd.Text) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tbxMedd.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Skriv in ditt meddelande");
            }
            else
            {
                byte[] utData = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("<" + " " + namn + " " + ">" + "  " + tid + ":" + "\t" + tbxMedd.Text + "\r\n");
                try
                {
                    tbxLogg.AppendText("<" + " " + namn + " " + ">" + "  " + tid + ":" + "\t" + tbxMedd.Text + "\r\n");
                    await klient.GetStream().WriteAsync(utData, 0, utData.Length);
                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(error.Message, Text);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        tbxMedd.Clear();
    }
    public async void StartReading(TcpClient k)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int n = 0;
        try
        {
            n = await k.GetStream().ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 1024);
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.Message, Text);
            return;
        }
        tbxLogg.AppendText(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, n));
        StartReading(k);
    }
    private void Klient_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (klient != null)
            klient.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: `n = await k.GetStream().ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 1024);` check `n<=0`

Comment: The best way is for the client to always close connection.  The server should capture the close event that comes from the client.   Then the server should close the socket.  TCP is reliable.  Which means that every message get ack from the other end of the connection.  This applies to the close message.  So when the client sends a close (FIN) the server will send back a close ACK (FIN ACK).  The ack takes place automatically at the low level socket driver.  If the server closes before the ack occurs an exception will occur like the one you are seeing.

Comment: Eser : Have you every try your solution?  I do not think it will work.  Stream often go to zero in the middle of a receive message.

Comment: @jdweng have **you** tried? No it can't. it means stream is closed...

Comment: Read Async only gets one datagram.  If you have a message with more than one datagram (over 1500 bytes) will your code work?

Comment: @jdweng it is a tcp connections. and if a read returns <=0 that means *end of stream*, datagram sizes etc are irrelevant for tcp

Comment: The thing is, the crash occurs when I close a klient. I think I have to send an information to my server that, whenever a client closes, the server should delete the client from itself. How can I manage this?

Comment: @MAA  please add a single check before calling `StartReading(k);` as I said and then post the result

Comment: @Eser should I check with if-condition?

Comment: @MAA `if(n<=0) close client connection and return. Nothing to do anymore`. BTW: there are other issues with your code :(

Comment: @MAA There is no *stop*. Close the connection and forget it.

Comment: @MAA That is enough. Use google

Comment: Eser : What you said is wrong about tcp with respect to datagram is irrelevant.  The stream handles multiple datagrams.  But nobody is ever going to get your code working with you providing one line of code.  You answer is useless.

Comment: @jdweng Sorry, I am not going to argue with you. I have written millions of tcp/udp related codes and I know what I said. BTW: you should know what is *comment* and what is *answer* by now

Comment: @jdweng `Have you every try your solution?`, `You answer is useless` . Why are you so rude? anything personally with me?

Comment: @Eser Works now when I close the client and checking n<=0..The crash is gone. However for everytime I send something from my other clients, I always get an error message from the catch thing under the try(n = await [...]), stating: 
"Can't reach a deleted object. Objectname: System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient"

Comment: @MAA update your codes in question accordingly

Comment: @Eser Done that

Comment: @MAA add a `return` after `klient.Close();` BTW: you may want to remove from `klientLista`. But don't forget. accesing an object from multiple treads needs *synchronization*. use *lock*.

Comment: @Eser Thanks, works perfectly! Highly appreciating the help man!

Comment: @MAA I still see some problems, but let's happen, that will make you learn.

Comment: When the server crashes, do you get a stack trace? Can you add that to the question? If something hits 100% CPU usage, you should be able to hit 'break' in the VS debugger and see what line of code its hitting, then stepping through to see where it's looping.